# How to create subdirectories under [WindowsVolume]MyNewDir

Tags: visual-studio, wix

I want to create two subdirectories under [WindowsVolume]MyNewDir. SubDir1 and SubDir2. How I achieve that. Below is my code:

```
<?define ProductVersion = "13.1.2.3"?>
<?define ProductUpgradeCode = "12345678-1234-1234-1234-111111111112"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)" Name="MyProgram"
         Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="COMPANY" Language="1033">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="product.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="MyProgram" />
           <Directory Id="ANOTHERLOCATION" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <SetDirectory Id="ANOTHERLOCATION" Value="[WindowsVolume]MyNewDir" />


    <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Level="1">
      <Component Directory="INSTALLDIR">
        <File Id="ApplicationFile1" Source="C:\Users\user\Desktop\myprogram.exe" />
      </Component>
      <Component Directory="ANOTHERLOCATION">
        <File Id="ApplicationFile2" Source="C:\Users\user\Desktop\InstallerFiles_13_4_9_3\myprogramLauncher.jar" />
      </Component>
    </Feature>
</Product>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the base directory, in this case WindowsVolume, from there you can create any directory structure that will be created with your installer, then you can reference the new directories to put your files there.

Try this:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="MyProgram" />
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME" >
        <Directory Id="ANOTHERLOCATION" Name="MyNewDir">
            <Directory Id="DIR1" Name="SubDir1" />
            <Directory Id="DIR2" Name="SubDir2" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
      </Directory>
</Directory>

<SetDirectory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME" Value="[WindowsVolume]" />

<Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Level="1">
  <Component Directory="INSTALLDIR">
    <File Id="ApplicationFile1" Source="C:\Users\user\Desktop\myprogram.exe" />
  </Component>
  <Component Directory="DIR1">
    <File Id="ApplicationFile2" Source="C:\Users\user\Desktop\InstallerFiles_13_4_9_3\myprogramLauncher.jar" />
  </Component>
</Feature>
```

Comment: Thanks Rolo. My application creating some temporary folders inside InstallDirectory and windows Volume directory. When I uninstall my application then these  temporary folders still there. I want to delete all temp folders or files. Can you please suggest how I achieve that.

Comment: @user3817749 If this help you solve your problem with directories, you should mark as accepted answer. Cleaning up files/folders is a completely different question, for that you may want to look for "RemoveFile" and "RemoveFolder" elements.You should avoid mixing questions on SO.